# How to use variable with another tpl file?

Tags: templates, smarty

I have order.tpl that $ordermub variable is working. I want to use the same $ordermub variable it orderdtls.tpl (When i use the same variable, its does not works)

Its possible to work without modify php?

Comment: Nobody there for this question?

Comment: Its a bit thin to give a precise answer. Please describe your template structure and have a look into the Smarty manual (e.g. here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variable.scopes.tpl).

Comment: Yes, exactly this one.

Comment: Any other can give response this query?

Comment: Please describe your template structure, p.e. add some code to work with.

Comment: Basically, i cannot enter php code due to php is encrypted thats why i want to override the variable to another tpl anyway.